# Is the C# random number generator guaranteed to be stable?

Tags: c#, random

I am writing a program which uses a lot of random numbers to generate stuff. But I want to assure that when starting with the same seed the generated content is the same. So when I create my random number like this:

```
Random r = new Random(seed);
int num = r.Next();
```

How is it guaranteed that num is always the same over time (means: several releases of .NET)? Is there a standardized list in the background? Or should I use my own "random list" to be sure that this will never change?

Comment: It looks like the seed algorithm hasn't changed between [.NET Framework](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,bb77e610694e64ca) and [.NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Random.cs,bb77e610694e64ca), if that helps. I can't find a specific statement on compatibility, but given that the team try very hard not to break anything, I would be very surprised if this algorithm changed in a non-backwards-compatible way

Comment: Doesn't sound like what you want is actually random? Maybe you want to generate a list of random integers once but then reuse that list multiple times?

Comment: @PeonProgrammer: This is exactly what I ment with: "Or should I use my own "random list" to be sure that this will never change?"

Comment: The default constructor form Random() uses the system time so all you are doing with Seed is changed the starting parameter for the Random Class.  The Random class is using a fixed algorithm for generating the sequence so it will always be the same.

Comment: @jdweng If I got it right, the question was if using the same seed between different versions of .NET produces the exact same sequences.

Comment: Only Microsoft knows that answer.  Microsoft often changes default values when releasing new Net Versions.  You have no control over the decision making at Microsoft.

Comment: @jdweng: HimBromBeere is right.

Comment: No, the result can vary across versions of the framework, and it's [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random) here - _"The implementation of the random number generator in the Random class isn't guaranteed to remain the same across major versions of the .NET Framework. As a result, you shouldn't assume that the same seed will result in the same pseudo-random sequence in different versions of the .NET Framework."_

Comment: @stuartd I think this is answer-worthy.

Comment: If you need stability you need to write your own generator. Note that you should not look for a list but at an [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the result from the same seed can vary across versions of the framework, and it's [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random) here:

> The implementation of the random number generator in the Random class isn't guaranteed to remain the same across major versions of the .NET Framework. As a result, **you shouldn't assume that the same seed will result in the same pseudo-random sequence in different versions of the .NET Framework**.

That documentation also contains variations of this advice in other sections, e.g. in [Retrieve the same sequence of random values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netcore-3.1#retrieve-the-same-sequence-of-random-values):

> The following example uses 100100 as an arbitrary seed value to instantiate the Random object, displays 20 random floating-point values, and persists the seed value. It then restores the seed value, instantiates a new random number generator, and displays the same 20 random floating-point values. **Note that the example may produce different sequences of random numbers if run on different versions of the .NET Framework.**

And:

> However, note that Random objects in **processes running under different versions of the .NET Framework may return different series of random numbers even if they're instantiated with identical seed values**.

Answer (score 4):

To be explicit: no, there isn't a "standardized list" - it is a [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), so it just does the same mathematical operations over and over and over - which does make it predictable (deterministic) from the same seed, ***as long as*** no-one changes the PRNG algorithm being used. Given that people often use `Random` for things like seeding test data, I think it would cause an outcry if it suddenly changed (without it being opt-in in some way, like a new constructor parameter), so I would find it *unlikely* to do so (and they haven't to date), but: if "unlikely" isn't good enough, you could always just implement any of a number of PRNG algorithms in your own code.